# Finding first integrals of $\frac{dx}{(z-y)^2}=\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{y}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have $y^2-z^2=C_1$ which follows easly from $\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{y}.$ Second should be $x+y(y-z)=C_2,$ but I don't know how to derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$\frac{\,dx}{(z-y)^2}=\frac{\,d(y-z)}{z-y}$$

$$\implies \,dx+(y-z)\,d(y-z)=0.$$

Comment: I believe I do not understand fundamental ideas. How did you get
$$\frac{\,dx}{(z-y)^2}=\frac{\,d(y-z)}{z-y}?$$

Comment: Keeping 1st ratio fixed and Subtracting 2nd & 3rd ratios..Read your text book first carefully...

Comment: Why am I allowed to do so? (it make no sense to me) Can you give me reference to some book  or webside with good explenation (I can't find any)? The problem is that I have some fundamental problems with solving this kind of exercise. I do understand method of characteristics, but when comes to doing exercise I stuck.

Comment: Btw. did you just done the following: $$\frac{\,dy}{z}-\frac{\,dz}{y}=\frac{\,d(y-z)}{z-y}?$$

Comment: @Fallen Apart : This is a general property of equal frations : $$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{A-C}{B-D}$$ Expand it to prove it.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{z}-\frac{dz}{y}$ is NOT equal to $\frac{dy-dz}{z-y}$, but : $$\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{y}=\frac{dy-dz}{z-y}$$ This is true only if $\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{y}$

Comment: @JJacquelin So you says
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}\implies\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{A-C}{B-D}$$
I would never figure it out. You are my hero!

Comment: Remember, more generally : $$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{c_1A+c_2C}{c_1B+c_2D}$$, with $c_1$ and $c_2$ constants.